# HTML full width video header

Tags: html, video, html5-video

How can I make a full width video header like this: http://mazwai.com/#/ ? Where the video is only at the top but you can scroll down past it?  I have seen a lot of tutorials for videos like this: http://thenewcode.com/samples/polina.html but you cannot scroll past the video here (even when there is content that goes past the video) - the video is always the background.  How can I make the first example?  Are there any tutorials anywhere?  I am having a hard time finding a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I use [jquery-background-video](https://github.com/BGStock/jquery-background-video) and it works pretty fine

Here is the code to make the video 100 window height

```
var $window = $(window);
var $video = $('.jquery-background-video-wrapper');
$(window).resize(function() {
    var height = $window.height();
    $video.css('height', height);
}).trigger('resize');
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.jquery-background-video').bgVideo();
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="jquery-background-video-wrapper" style="background-image: url('https://xxxx.jpg')">
    <video class="jquery-background-video" autoplay muted loop poster="https://xxxx.jpg">
        <source src="https://xxxx.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <script>document.getElementById('video-home').style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';</script>
    <div id="vido-scrollto"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

for the full width background video you can use data-bg-video="video path" class in html5.
below is the demo example just insert your data background video path.

```
 <section class="mbr-section mbr-section-hero mbr-section-full " id="header4-0" 
data-bg-video="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=La5GyrphjK0">

        <div class="mbr-overlay" style="opacity: 0.5; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>

        <div class="mbr-table-cell">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="mbr-section col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 text-xs-right">

                        <h1 class="mbr-section-title display-1">VIDEO BACKGROUND</h1>
                        <p class="mbr-section-lead lead">Intro with background video and color overlay. Text and buttons are aligned to right. Mobirise helps you cut down development time by providing you with a flexible website editor with a drag and drop interface.</p>
                        <div class="mbr-section-btn"><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#">Demo Button</a> <a class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" href="#">Demo Button</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mbr-arrow mbr-arrow-floating" aria-hidden="true"><a href="#next"><i class="mbr-arrow-icon"></i></a></div>

    </section>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `data-bg-video="video path"` ?  That is not a class